# How to en-/disable Menu-Object programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, menuitem

I would like to en-/disable a `Menu-Object` programmatically in Swift. I found something one the `Apple Developer Library`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMenuItem/enabled

But how to get a reference to the `Menu-Object` with the code and set its state programmatically?

Comment: Take a look at `validateMenuItem:`

Comment: @vadian Doesn't work

Comment: Menu item validation is very powerful but also very sensitive. It depends on a few settings in Interface Builder and your design. If the menu is not in the responder chain you might connect the delegate of the menu (not the menu item) to the class which handles the validation.

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 4+, some of the code in [Barath's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39095045/2824961) has become deprecated.  I also think the code is more adaptable by searching for menuitem titles rather than their index:

```
let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu!
let subMenu = mainMenu.item(withTitle: "Edit")?.submenu

subMenu?.item(withTitle: "Cut")?.isEnabled = false
```

Also, setting `isEnabled` to true or false will not toggle menu items as long as `setAutoenablesItems` is set to true.  It can be disabled from the storyboard or programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Enable or Disable menu item without subclassing with the following code.

```
let mainMenu = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu!
let appMenu = mainMenu.itemAtIndex(0)!.submenu

appMenu?.itemWithTitle("Title")?.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the enabled-attribute programmatically: `menObj.enabled = false`

Comment: How to get the `Menu-Object` to `menObj` now?

Comment: If you made a Storyboard you can get the connection to the Menu-Object through an IBOutlet. Then you have easy-access to all attributes.

Comment: Which subclass should the file have?

Comment: Try to learn what IBOutlets are. Every UIView element is compatible. - Get a short video instruction: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-iphone-app/getting-started-with-iphone/what-is-an-iboutlet-2

Comment: I'm able to create a connection to AppDelegate, but not to the Controller I'm needing.

Comment: Okay, it works now. But I'm not able to disable the `Menu-Object`, why not? Changing Title works for example.

Comment: "This property has no effect unless the menu in which the item will be added or is already a part of has been sent setAutoenablesItems:NO. If a menu item is disabled, its keyboard equivalent is also disabled. See the NSMenuValidation informal protocol specification for cautions regarding this method." See your link. You'll have to disable the Autoenable-function of your menue.

Comment: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`, but the variable is set as following `@IBOutlet weak var MenuItem: NSMenuItem!`

Comment: Did you link it through the Storyboard and the Assistant editor?

Comment: btw its always easier if you share whole code snippets

Comment: Yes, I linked it to AppDelegate (only this file worked): `@IBOutlet weak var theMenuItem: NSMenuItem!` After that I defined a function, which is called on initialisation and deinitialisation of the `Window Controller` using `NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu!.autoenablesItems = false`, but I didn't helped setting the state of `enabled`.

Comment: So it seems something is not doing right. You have to link it to the correct ViewController that is linked to the Storyboard

Comment: You could upload your code and i will check what is going wrong

Comment: Shure you're meaning `View Controller`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution with Swift 5+

```
hamburgerMenuItem.isEnabled = false
```